# PHP modify return

Tags: php

Hello i try do next logic

i have two class

```
abstract class Repository {

}


class HomeRepository extends Reposytory {
  public function getMyAwesome() {
    return array()
  }

}
```

i dont wish get array, i wish get object, but i wish do some little magic,
i create hydrator class, his create object from array

now this seems like

```
public function getMyAwesome()
    {
        $awesomes = $this->adapter->table('awesome')->get();
        $result = [];
        foreach ($awesomes as $aw) {
            $result[] = $this->hydrator->hydrate($aw);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

but i dont wish do this in child class, i wish enter this to parent, or gate
another word i wish see in my child class next code

```
 public function getMyAwesome()
        {
            return $this->adapter->table('awesome')->get(); //MUST BE HYDRATED
        }
```

How i can do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php

Comment: Maybe magic methods? Have a look at `__call`

Comment: @tereško yes, but i wish work not only with PDO, and i wish improve my understood in php.

Comment: PDO is part of php. If you do not want to use this, you need to create a [mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) class, that will populate the entity with the retrieved values.

Comment: @tereško see, i wish change adapter in child repository. i wish do gate to child repo answer. Gate must hydrate all repo return, but i dont wish call gate in my child like this `hydrate(Myrepo->getAll())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, answer is very simple. Must use Proxy Class